# Generic Instance for GADT in Haskell

Tags: haskell, serialization

I'm attempting to serialize data types in Haskell, and would like to know how to serialize a GADT. The method I have attempted looks something like (using Control.DeepSeq):

```
data Gadt a where 
  Cons1 :: Int -> Gadt Int
  Cons2 :: Bool -> Gadt Bool

instance NFData Cons1 where rnf = genericRnf
instance NFData Cons2 where rnf = genericRnf

deriveSafeCopy ......
```

However, this does not compile: GHC tells me that Cons1 and Cons2 are not valid constructors. I can serialize standard data types just fine. What is the optimal way to serialize GADTs?

The reason I want to serialize GADTs is since this data type is a key in a Redis Database that I'm using for my project.

Comment: woops .. I just saw that this will not work at all - the cases you defined yield this functions: `Cons1 :: forall a . a -> Gadt Int` so I think you are really trying to do something else?

Comment: You may want to look into [instant-generics](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/instant-generics), which is intended to deal with GADTs generically. I haven't looked very far into it myself yet, but it seems interesting.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I ddid want Cons1 :: Int -> Gadt Int. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

### disclaimer

**this does not answer the question about `generics` as @luqui pointed out**

---

ok turns out your definition is kindof strange (note that the `a` in `Cons1 :: a ->` is a `forall a` and is not related to the `a` in `Gadt a` - I cannot see what you did try to do here - sorry)

Basically you could put any value you want int there like

```
- Cons1 "Hello" -- :: Gadt Int
- Cons2 'c'     -- :: Gadt Bool
- Cons2 [1,2,3] -- :: Gadt Bool
```

all would give you either a `Gadt Int` or a `Gadt Bool` - but when you pattern match on it there is no way to make anything meaningful with the value as it really could be anything (including something which is not an instance of `NFData` itself)

---

But in principle you declare instances just like you would with normal ADTs - that is by giving defining `rnf` in here for the different cases.

So let's say I change your GADT into this:

```
data Gadt a where 
  Cons1 :: Int  -> Gadt Int
  Cons2 :: Bool -> Gadt Bool
```

then this instance declaration would be fine:

```
instance NFData (Gadt a) where
    rnf (Cons1 a) = rnf a
    rnf (Cons2 a) = rnf a
```

Comment: Helpful observations, just pointing out that it does not answer the question about generics

Comment: I still can't make generics on GADTs. If I try to make Gadt derive Generics, I get :   
  "Can't make a derived instance of ‘Generic (Gadt a)’:
      Constructor ‘Cons1' has existentials or constraints in its type"

Comment: @TimothyChu this is still with the `Cons1 :: a -> Gadt Int` right?` - the problem is in the first part where I try to explain why the `a` here can be *anything* (this is the *existentials* the compiler is complaining about - there is a [good article about this on wiki.Haskell.org](https://wiki.haskell.org/Existential_type) )

Comment: @TimothyChu The GHC generics mechanism does not support constructors like those in your question. Generally all GADT constructors with indices are excluded from having a Generic instance. If you want generics for this type, there is indeed a library for generics with indexed data types - it was mentioned in a comment on your question.